Was there a clip in Oswald's rifle, and did it contain any ammunition?
Report of the President's Commission on the Assassination of President John F. Kennedy | 1964:

p.8
…
Searching the sixth floor.
Deputy Sheriff Luke Mooney noticed a pile of cartons in the southeast comer.
He squeezed through the boxes and realized immediately that he had discovered the point from which the shots had been fired.
On the floor were three empty cartridge cases.
A carton had apparently been placed on the floor at the side of the window so that a person sitting on the carton
could look down Elm Street toward the overpass and scarcely be noticed from the outside.
…
p.9
Mooney's discovery intensified the search for additional evidence on the sixth floor, and at 1 :22 p.m.,
approximately 10 minutes after the cartridge cases were found,
Deputy Sheriff Eugene Boone turned his flashlight in the direction of two rows of boxes in the northwest corner near the staircase.
Stuffed between the two rows was a bolt-action rifle with a telescopic sight.
The rifle was not touched until it could be photographed.
When Lt. J. C. Day of the police identification bureau decided that the wooden stock and the metal knob
at the end of the bolt contained no prints, he held the rifle by the
stock while Captain Fritz ejected a live shell by operating the bolt.
Lieutenant Day promptly noted that stamped on the rifle itself was
the serial number "C2766" as well as the markings "1940" "MADE ITALY" and "CAL. 6.5."
The rifle was about 40 inches long and when disassembled it could fit into a handmade paper sack which, after the
assassination, was found in the southeast comer of the building within a few feet of the cartridge cases.
…
p.79 — Discovery of Cartridge Cases and Rifle
Shortly after the assassination, police officers arrived at the Depository Building and began a search for the assassin and evidence.
Around 1 p.m. Deputy Sheriff Luke Mooney noticed a pile of cartons
in front of the window in the southeast comer of the sixth floor. (See Commission Exhibit No. 723, p. 80.)
Searching that area he found at approximately 1 :12 p.m. three empty cartridge cases on the floor near the window.
When he was notified of Mooney's discovery, Capt. J. W. Fritz, chief of the homicide bureau of the Dallas Police Department, issued instructions that nothing be moved or touched until technicians from the police crime laboratory could take photographs and check for fingerprints.
Mooney stood guard to see that nothing was disturbed.
A few minutes later, Lt. J. C. Day of the Dallas Police Department arrived and took photographs of the cartridge cases before anything had been moved.
At 1 :22 p.m. Deputy Sheriff Eugene Boone and Deputy Constable Seymour Weitzman found a bolt-action rifle with a telescopic sight
between two rows of boxes in the northwest corner near the staircase on the sixth floor.
No one touched the weapon or otherwise disturbed the scene until Captain Fritz and Lieutenant Day arrived and the weapon was photographed as it lay on the floor.
After Lieutenant Day determined that there were no fingerprints on the knob of the bolt and that the wooden stock was too rough to take fingerprints, he picked the rifle up by the stock and held it that way while Captain Fritz opened the bolt and ejected a live round.
Lieutenant Day retained possession of the weapon and took it back to the police department for examination.
Neither Boone nor Weitzman handled the rifle.
p.555
…
The clip itself is inserted into the rifle by drawing back the bolt, and pushing the clip in from the top.
The clip holds one to six cartridges.
If six cartridges are inserted into the clip and an additional cartridge is inserted into the chamber,
up to seven bullets can be fired before reloading.
…
Apart from the cartridge in the rifle, three expended cartridge cases were found in the southeast portion
of the sixth floor of the Texas School Book Depository Building, lying between the south
p.557
wall and a high stack of boxes which ran parallel to the wall.
The cartridge cases were a short distance to the west of the southeast corner window in that wall.
p.599 — REPORT OF CAPT. J. W. FRITZ, DALLAS POLICE DEPARTMENT
We conducted the Investigation at the Texas School Book repository building on November 22, 1963, immediately after the President was shot and after we had found the location where Lee Harvey Oswald had done the shooting from and left three empty cartridge cases on the floor and the rifle had been found partially hidden under some boxes near the back stairway.
These pieces of evidence were protected until the Crime Lab could get pictures and make a search for fingerprints.
After Lt. Day, of the Crime Lab, had finished his work with the rifle, I picked it up and found that it had a cartridge in the chamber, which I ejected.
About this time some officer came to me and told me that Mr. Roy S. Truly wanted to see me, as one of his men had left the building.
I had talked to Mr. Truly previously, and at that time he thought everyone was accounted for who worked in the building.
Mr. Truly then came with another officer and told me that Lee Harvey Oswald had left the building'.
I asked if he had an address where this man lived, and he told me that he did, that it was in Irving at 2515 W. 5th Street.
I then left the rest of the search of the building with Chief Lumpkin and other officers who were' there …

There were three spent casings on the floor, corresponding to the three reported shots, and one live round in the chamber, but only an implication that there was no ammunition in the magazine.
One would normally put a full clip into the magazine, and since there's no advantage to having less ammunition, it seems unnatural that Oswald didn't load the rifle with a full complement of six rounds (or even seven).
I can't find anything that says whether the rifle even contained a clip, empty or otherwise.
The possibilities are:

No clip in the magazine.
An empty clip in the magazine.
A loaded clip (likely 2 or 3 rounds) in the magazine.

Is there any documentation that mentions the clip and its contents, or explicitly says that there were only four rounds?
Note: This question is looking for documented facts, not for speculation about conspiracy theories.

It's unlikely that any such evidence does, or even could, exist. Reason is that finding three casings neither affirms nor refutes the possibility that Oswald picked up however many empty casings he could quickly spot before departing.

@PieterGeerkens though it breaks the trail of evidence somewhat, the rest could have been recovered from his body after he was shot. I think only 3 shots were recorded as having been fired, no rounds were found on his body, so we can guess at most another 3 unmentioned rounds left in the magazine of the rival.

@jwenting: Oswald was apprehended about 45 minutes after the assassination, at the Oak Cliff movie theater (2 or 3 miles from Dealey Plaza, depending how you choose to measure). That provided ample time and opportunity to dispose of any cartridges picked up at the scene.

Just curiosity: the first statement is based solely on Mooney's testimony or there were witnesses?

@PieterGeerkens says "finding three casings neither affirms nor refutes the possibility that Oswald picked up however many empty casings he could quickly spot before departing". I've changed the question slightly to include the clip itself, which is a more tangible subject.

@RogerV. asks "the first statement is based solely on Mooney's testimony or there were witnesses?" — The best I can find (which doesn't mean that better doesn't exist) is page 79 (just added), which mentions Captain Fritz (in charge of the investigation) being there, and page 599, which is Fritz's testimony.

The clip is mentioned very next sentence on page 555-same source as sited by the OP: When the rifle was found in the Texas School Book Depository Building it contained a clip 23 which bore the letters "SMI" (the manufacturer's markings) and the number "952" (possibly a part number or the manufacturer's code number).24 The rifle probably was sold without a clip; however, the clip is commonly available.25

@justCal — I must be going blind. That answers my question, as there's no reason to think that the clip wasn't empty. Thank you.  (It doesn't solve my problem (where are the other 2 or 3 rounds that should have been in the clip?), but any answers to that would be speculation.)

I hate to bring it up, but it does raise a possible issue. I have watched couple of videos this morning on shooting these rifles. When one of these Carcano rifles loads its last round into the chamber, it ejects the empty clip out the bottom of the rifle. I am not sure how a single round could be found in a rifle with a clip in place. This might indicate at least one more round must have been present in the clip.

@justCal says "I hate to bring it up" — So the reported configuration is impossible without being deliberately set that way. (If it wasn't empty, the ejection of the cartridge in the chamber would have loaded another one.) There are so many things about this event that don't make sense, while at the same time having no reasonable explanation even if there were a conspiracy. (The state of clip etc. is mostly irrelevant, except for the fact that it shouldn't be that way.) Thanks, I think.
